# Create a list of binary trees with max height n

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, racket

A node is a

```
(define-struct node (left right))
```

A leafy binary tree (LBT) is one of

```
; - 'leaf
; - (make-node LBT LBT)
```

I have to design a function that takes in a natural number n and creates a list of all leafy binary trees that have height n.
So for example, a height of 2 should return:

```
`(list 
(make-node 'leaf (make-node 'leaf 'leaf)) 
(make-node (make-node 'leaf 'leaf) 'leaf) 
(make-node (make-node 'leaf 'leaf) (make-node 'leaf 'leaf)))`
```

I've been stuck on this assignment for days now. The best I could come up with was:

```
`(define (lbt-list n)
  (cond [(= 0 n) 'leaf]
        [(= 1 n) (cons (make-node (lbt-list (- n 1)) (lbt-list (- n 1))) empty)]
        [else (list (make-node (first (lbt-list (- n 1))) (lbt-list (- n n)))
                    (make-node (lbt-list (- n n)) (first (lbt-list (- n 1))))
                    (make-node (first (lbt-list (- n 1))) (first (lbt-list (- n 1)))))]))`
```

The problem involves recursion and I'm just not sure how to fully code out this function. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?  In what way(s) is what it produces different from what it should?

Comment: The problem with my code is past heights of 2, my code wont give a list of ALL possible trees, just 3 possible trees

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make nodes out of lists; the only valid arguments to `make-node` are `leaf`s and `node`s.  Instead, you should take the results of `lbt-list` and use each of its elements to make each of the `node`s for the list to be returned.

Also, you never use the `rest` of any returned `lbt-list`.

Comment: There are no calls to `make-node` with list arguments - `(lbt-list (- n n))` resolves to `'leaf`.

Answer (score 1):

To start, the reason why you're only getting three trees is that your `else` clause calls `list` with exactly three instances of `make-node`. This might be a little easier to see if you make `(= n 1)` your base case, and explicitly use `'leaf` wherever you need it, instead of `(lbt-list (- n n))`.

I think you'll benefit from stepping back from the code for a second and asking yourself what mathematical products you're trying to generate. In particular, how do you get the *n*-depth binary trees from the *(n-1)*-depth binary trees?

It's simplest to break it into three parts. Here are two big hints:

- is `make-node` commutative?
- how is the level-on-level generation related to a *Cartesian product*?

Finally, helper functions are your friend here - they'll go a long way towards dividing the mental burden of generating the list into smaller pieces. I wrote three helper functions when I threw together a solution, but you might be able to make do with two.